# Programming as a Pen Tester in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I am trying to get into the Penatration Testing Industry. So far I haven't felt the need to learn a new language yet because everyone sais its not **required**, and most of the work done in the terminal is just basic input and output for programs like nmap, metasploit, etc. However from time to time I will have to make a Bash Script to automate a process faster.

I'm not trying to make the next Nmap, or metasploit, which is why Im not in any rush to learn the computer languages they were built on. But I am trying to use those tools to my advantage when testing, by manipulating the data that it outputs or saving data to directories. Which is why im leaning more twords Bash and text-processing, but I still need a better understanding on the difference, so I know which option is best for someone in my situation.

- How limited is Bash/Shell compared to other languages for Terminal tasks?
- Is grep, awk and sed the best option for text-processing in Bash?

**Conclusion**

Is continuing with Bash and Text-processing the best option for someone like me that just wants to automate processes and manipulate data in a terminal? or would a computer language be better for tasks like this?

Comment: This question is really opinion based and so is almost certain to be closed (I've voted for that myself as it's really not a good fit for the site).  However, I hope you stick around on the site!  Answer some questions and grow a bit of reputation (not very hard) and next time, asking this sort of question in chat is a better approach when what you want is more of a discussion than a single, objectively correct answer.  (See the help pages for more detail on what is on and off topic for questions on the site.)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion Wildcard, but I can access chat without a certain amount of reputation, which I can't get without asking or answering questions which is what i am trying to do. What a catch 22

Comment: Not really, though.  It might take you a couple days of very part time answering to get the necessary reputation.  When I was starting out on the site (with little experience I might add), I used question answering as an opportunity to research and learn. Find a question about something I'd like to know too, dig into the documentation and find the answer or invent the code for the answer, and get 10, 20 or 30 reputation points—easy. The barrier for chat entry is actually low, but it does mean you have to *contribute* to the site. It seems tough compared to e.g. captchas, but you'll make it. :)

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm spending the time to write these comments is that you strike me as someone who I'd very much like to see as a regular contributor on this site.  A self-learner!  :)  Some people write "show me teh codez" type questions (which are at least specific questions with definite answers, though low quality), but you're asking *what should you learn,* which implies that you can go ahead and then learn it.  I like it!  (And see, you're up to 11 rep already.)

Comment: I really appreciate all the help and encouragement. Most people would just post an answer or move on but the fact that you are really trying to help, motivates me to try to help someone. I asked this question mainly because I feel like I've been wasting my time learning the wrong stuff or programming the wrong way. I like Pen Testing because these days, it's vital for technology, but so is programming. And both paths cross frequently so I just wanted someone to point me in the right direction, which you have done for me with a little help from others in here. Thanks @Wildcard and everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You don't *have* to ***fully*** learn a language for Pentesting, but it is good if you do.

For Pentesting, there are numerous scripts available on the internet, you can always just look around and find what you are looking for.

Python and Shell are the languages you are going to use most for Pentesting. It would be good if you learnt them both well, imagine you somehow managed to get into the victims computer, you are not going to google and search for scripts while you are in there, your goal is to finish your task **ASAP**, Python and Shell both will be your best friend.

I suggest you learn them both perfectly, because if you plan on becoming a Pentester, without the knowledge of Python and Shell you will be left behind.

For your text processing needs, `sed`, `AWK` and `grep` are perfect, occasionally, Python can also be used for text processing.

### Why learn Python?

Usually, a big percentage of the computer's that run Linux, will have Python installed, Python comes pre installed for every Linux OS AFAIK, so if you manage to get into your victims computer, you will almost always be able to run Python scripts, unless they removed Python, which I highly doubt they did.

To sum this up, you don't *have* to fully learn a language, but it is good if you know a thing or two about Python and Shell. You will also need a good understanding of how Linux works.

### Some resources to get you started :

[Learn Penetration testing with Python](http://zempirians.com/ebooks/Learning%20Penetration%20Testing%20with%20Python.pdf)

[Hands on Penetration testing](https://repo.zenk-security.com/Magazine%20E-book/Penetration%20Testing%20-%20A%20hands-on%20introduction%20to%20Hacking.pdf)

[Github - awesome-pentest](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-pentest)

Comment: I am a little familiar with Python, but I haven't tried to REALLY learn it because the scripts I'm working on now just requre text-processing. But I'm not too familiar with sed or awk. Do I have to learn both or can 1 do it all?

Comment: @KyleCurtis, sorry can't help you with that question, I don't know too much about text processing, I am sure if you google `sed` vs `awk` vs `grep`, you will get answers showing the difference between all 3.

Comment: @KyleCurtis, learn basic use of `grep`, then learn basic use of `sed`, then learn basic use of `awk`, then learn advanced uses of `grep` and `sed` more or less concurrently, then learn advanced use of `awk`.  And **definitely** learn shell, thoroughly.  You might start with the shell learning resources I've linked to from my profile (all but one are questions/answers on this very site).